# express app: where to place a closed loop temperature control

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

i am new in express.js, i´ve only built some small client/server apps.

Now i want to create a temperature-controller with a PID-component. I don´t understand the architecture of express.js enough to decide where to place what.

I have a router to get the targetvalue from my Web-Client - that works. And 
I have a router to get the current temperature-value. And third have a router to control the heatingelement.

Now i need somewhat of a loop, in which for every some seconds i can compare this values and calculate my output-value and send that value to my heatingelement.

Where to place what?

Greets, Freisei.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you don't use a loop for this kind of thing, you use an [Interval, set up with setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
function doTheControlOperation() {
  const setPoint = //get the temp set point
  const current  = //get the most recent temperature reading
  const diff = current - setPoint
  if (diff < 0)  // turn on the element
  else // turn off the element
}

var howOften = 10000 //ten seconds in milliseconds

setInterval (doTheControlOperation, howOften)
```

This code calls doTheControlOperation() every ten seconds.

I'm sure you know this kind of control system usually contains some hysteresis and protection against short-cycling. My example doesn't do any of that, obviously.

Comment: thank you, but this answer does not address my question. I need to know what is the best practice to place that construct.